# How to fetch the JSON formated data

Tags: php, json

I need to fetch the value of 'message' which is json formated in php

```
{"status":"error","message":" phone_name or phone_number already exist"}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Could you post your current code so we know what you've tried?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Google

Comment: if I echo result i'm getting like {"status":"error","message":" phone_name or phone_number already exist"} but i 'm not able to fetch the message value.

Comment: read the manual first : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
$json = '{"status":"error","message":" phone_name or phone_number already exist"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->{'message'}; // phone_name or phone_number already exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode(json_string) to convert it into php array.
Then you can access it as array["message"]